# Pure Change of Base

Tags: c++, math, numbers

I'm trying (without much success) to write a short c++ function:

double digit(double x, int b, int d)

that returns the d-th digit in base-b expansion of the number x, which can be positive or negative, and can be a fraction. when d is negative, it should return the after-the-decimal-dot digits (its underfined for d=0 so say it returns 0 in that case).
For example:

```
    const double x = 25.73;
    for (int n = -5; n <= 5; n++)
            cout<<digit(x,10,n)<<' ';
```

should print:
0
0
0
3
7
0 
5
2
0
0
0

The function must use only loops, if, exp, pow, log, floor and ceil. i.e., without sprintf tricks etc.

Thanks!!!

EDIT: For simplicity, assume 2<=b<=10

EDIT: Please also avoid using mod, only pow-exp-log-floor-ceil based solutions

Comment: Writing a specific digit in double is probably not a good idea, since the representation of double not exactly decimal point arithemtic, it is a floating point arithmetic. For example, 1.1 could be represented as 1.099999999999 or 1.10000000001 (just examples, not real cases here)

Comment: "(its underfined for d=0 so say it returns 0 for d=0)" WHY?

Comment: what is the value of b in the above example?

Comment: amit: you're definitely right. i need it to do a bit broader trick.
Cheers: ok, so it should print '.' where d=0. please note that this is the location of the decimal point.
Aravind: it's 10, i'll fix the q
thanks all!

Comment: What is "base-b expansion of number x"?

Comment: counting base, like b=2 for binary, b=10 for decimal etc

Comment: regarding "ok, so it should print '.' where d=0.", how do you get the `double` result of a function to print as "."? methinks these requirements can't have been part of the original assignment text. why not reproduce that text here *literally* (or with a reference if it's publicly available).

Comment: by the way, **what is the question**

Comment: cheers: this is exactly why I said 0 rather than '.'. so we have the first line: if (d==0) return 0;. now the question is, how should the next lines be written :)

Comment: If you can use loops but not mod, is it ok to repeatedly subtract base to re-create mod? Are there any other artificial restrictions you won't mention until someone's answered? What _is_ the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the most straightforward implementation, and it seems to work just fine.

```
int digit( double x, int base, int index ) {
    // shift number (mult by power of base) so desired digit is in one's place
    x = std::abs( x ) * std::pow( base, - index );
    // fmod strips higher digits; floor strips lower digits, leaving result.
    return std::floor( std::fmod( x, base ) );
}
```

I changed the return type from `double` to `int` since it doesn't make sense to have a fraction in  a digit. And it doesn't return `.` for 0, because again that's not a digit. The 0'th place value is the one's place.

Also this ignores the minus sign; you didn't define the "base-b expansion" for negative numbers. You could adjust the function to return b's complement notation or whatever.

By substituting `x` you can make this into one line, so it will satisfy the requirements for `constexpr` on platforms where the math functions are `constexpr` as well.

Comment: this looks wonderful. can you please think of a way to avoid mod?

Comment: @TroyMcClure No. That wasn't part of your question, and it's completely unreasonable. Guh, you could avoid `mod` by dividing by the next greater power of `base`, rounding multiplying and subtracting. Yuck, now my brain feels sick.

Comment: Can you take an example and explain please?I really want to know how this works, its looks pretty neat.For example what happens when we call:
cout<<digit(3.4562,2,3);

Thank you.

Comment: @Aravind Try it and see - you can step through examples in a debugger (or build it to print intermediate values) faster than typing them into a browser and waiting for us to answer you.

Comment: @Aravind I added comments, does that help?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: this works wonderful. also with the following: double mymod(double x, int n)
{
        return x-floor(x/n)*n;
}

Comment: @TroyMcClure Mind if I ask what this is for? If you don't have `fmod`, that suggests you're on a very limited system.

Comment: my main cause in this question is mathematical understanding. it's not for programming purposes, but I need to mathematically write it very accurately, so I'm verifying it with simple programs

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this in two steps.

1.Convert a number to base b

2.Find the d-th digit and return it.

The reason for splitting the tasks is because if you are repeatedly calling for the same set of base and number and only for different d's, then we can cache the number in the new base.For example the following function converts a number **a** from base 10, to a base **b**.I am curious how to deal with fractions.

```
string changeBase(int a,int b)
{
  string A="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  string res="";
  while(a>=b)
  {
      res=A[a%b]+res;
      a=a/b;
  }
  return res;
 }
```

We need to return as a string as the new base can have digits like 'A' or 'B' or the like, which represent remainders of 10, 11, and so on.
Then we can play around with the returned string as in:

```
 string A=changeBase(24,2);
 cout<<A[0];//for some d
```

For negative support you can use the string index appropriately based on how you define it for negative **d**.

Comment: It's a red flag that your implementation has a different number of arguments from his prototype…

Comment: I was only trying to help, I don't know how to deal with double, which I have mentioned in my answer, please read fully.Thank you for your comment.Please tell how I can convert double into other bases, I can't follow your code.Care to explain?

Comment: `double` is a basic type that stores fractions (floating-point numbers) as well as integers. Numbers aren't in a particular base when they are manipulated by mathematical operations. Base notation is something used by humans when writing numbers but there's no need to convert a number stored as `int` or `double` from base 10.